# UIPickerView with "non selectable" row

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uipickerview

I have a pickerview which works with a tableView. When the user select a row in the picker, the value is send back to the tableview in the current selectedCell. For this part, this is fine.
But the tricky thing is that i want when the user select a value in the picker, this value should not be "selectable", except if the user change the value in tableview by selecting another value in the picker.

=> The picker aim to update field in tableview. And each picker row can only be use once but remain visible with a check mark or something.

Unfortunately, i can't find a way to do this.

Has anyone an idea ?

Thanks in advance,

Thanks all !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `userInteractionEnabled` property of the picker to `NO` when you don't need the value to be changed? You can set it to `YES` when you need to enable it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. I guess this is my english which cause a missunderstood. I didn't want the full picker to be locked. Only the already selected row.